# ngInfiniteScroll is not working on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-scroll

I'm having issues to make Firefox working with the ng-infinite-scroll - v1.0.0 - 2013-02-23
Please look at this Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/dlrca98kgJIQxbzmqadt?p=preview
it works fine on Chrome and Safari on my Mac.
The latest release (ng-infinite-scroll - v1.1.0 - 2014-04-03) doesn't fixes this specific issue instead isn't working anymore on Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I'm having same issue did you found any workaround or a fix for this behavior?

Comment: @jayM  At that time the solution I found was to limit the execution of the directive to a specific div container, so I did a small modification to the code:  `$window = angular.element(#container);'